# Node.js how to connect to socket and send commands to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, groovy

I've been tasked with refactoring the below groovy code into Node.js

```
def sendHubCommand(String hubcmd){
    def s = new Socket("IP here", 6767)
    s.withStreams { inStream, outStream ->
        outStream << hubcmd + "\n"
        def reader = inStream.newReader()
        def responseText
        reader.ready()
        responseText = reader.readLine()
        //println "response = $responseText"
    }
    s.close();
    return true
}
```

I've messed around with the below node.js code and had no luck as client.write('nf sensor.contact') doesn't do anything once connected.

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(6767, 'IP here', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write('nf sensor.contact');
    });

    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Received: ' + data);
        client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
    });

    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });

  };
}
```

Essentially I need to open a socket and than be able to send a command to it like was being done in the groovy example but in node.js. Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the new keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the native net module, but I'm willing to bet it's the new keyword and a bit of your structure.

Try something like this instead:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = net.connect(6767, 'IP here', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('nf sensor.contact');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: This is assuming it is the client code of setting up the connection, and not the actual server code.